# What is the advantage of using Gradian to measure an angle?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, angle, applications, chain-rule

What is the advantage of Gradian to measure an angle? For example, I know radian is useful in Calculus because e.g. it simplifies the derivative of trigonometric functions.

By the way, except the question below, can someone tell me why radian measure in Calculus is the simplest? Why doesn't we need to use chain rule when calculating $\frac{d(\sin{x})}{dx}$ like what we do if the angle is in degree measure?

Comment: For an angle $x$ in degrees, $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x^\circ) = \frac{\pi}{180^\circ}\cos x^\circ$. Using degrees as the unit makes differentiation yield constants that make calculations complicated.

Comment: A right angle is $100$ gradians (AKA grades). Some like this number.

Comment: That's really two unrelated questions. The calculus question has been asked several times, including [Why do we require radians in calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/720924/139123)

Comment: As for the advantage of gradians, whatever it might be, it apparently is not a big enough advantage for most purposes. See [Why weren't “degrees” replaced with a more intuitive angle measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1834875/139123)

Answer (score 1):

the definition of $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ it’s literally $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{h}=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} $$ and from the last one you get the idea of the slope at some point of a function or “distance over time”, the gradient isn’t like sexagesimal degrees which measurement came from the proportion in area of a circle, it comes from counting the perimeter of a circumference of radius one (which is $2\pi$) and then the radians respects that proportion perimeter/radius and that’s why it makes everything more easy in my opinion.